# C# / .NET / "Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported" / "The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found"

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to start working with C# on a MAC.

I followed the guide here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code#faq

However, when I launch the project I get number 26 popping in the **PROBLEMS** tab and most of 'em say either "The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found" **OR** "Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported". It's obvious the IDE can't pull up the references or smth...

Below is some info on my system

```
democonsole: dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.101
 Commit:    b377529961

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.15
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.15-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.101/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.1
  Commit:  a1388f194c

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

~: code -v
1.42.0
ae08d5460b5a45169385ff3fd44208f431992451
x64
```

And here is my default app code (got it via **dotnet new console**):

```
using System;

namespace democonsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

**PROJECT JSON**

```
{
  "format": 1,
  "restore": {
    "/Users/doglabel/Desktop/democonsole/democonsole.csproj": {}
  },
  "projects": {
    "/Users/doglabel/Desktop/democonsole/democonsole.csproj": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "restore": {
        "projectUniqueName": "/Users/doglabel/Desktop/democonsole/democonsole.csproj",
        "projectName": "democonsole",
        "projectPath": "/Users/doglabel/Desktop/democonsole/democonsole.csproj",
        "packagesPath": "/Users/doglabel/.nuget/packages/",
        "outputPath": "/Users/doglabel/Desktop/democonsole/obj/",
        "projectStyle": "PackageReference",
        "configFilePaths": [
          "/Users/doglabel/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config"
        ],
        "originalTargetFrameworks": [
          "netcoreapp3.1"
        ],
        "sources": {
          "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json": {}
        },
        "frameworks": {
          "netcoreapp3.1": {
            "projectReferences": {}
          }
        },
        "warningProperties": {
          "warnAsError": [
            "NU1605"
          ]
        }
      },
      "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp3.1": {
          "imports": [
            "net461",
            "net462",
            "net47",
            "net471",
            "net472",
            "net48"
          ],
          "assetTargetFallback": true,
          "warn": true,
          "frameworkReferences": {
            "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
              "privateAssets": "all"
            }
          },
          "runtimeIdentifierGraphPath": "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.101/RuntimeIdentifierGraph.json"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!
P.S.I am fairly new to C# and .NET so please bear with me :)

Comment: Could you share your `project.json`? And VS Code version.

Comment: If you have a bin/ and obj/ folders delete them and then do a `dotnet build` again and see if that clears it up

Comment: @JonE doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: @KrivitskiyGrigoriy updated the original post with the info you requested. The VSCode version is 1.42.0

Comment: Ok, try to add `"omnisharp.path": "1.34.4-beta.7"` in your VS Code `settings.json`. And restart VS after this.

Comment: @KrivitskiyGrigoriy doesn't work either

Comment: Hm. You Net Core SDK and all paths in `project.json` are looking fine.

Comment: I recreate your environmetn: same version of VS and Net Core, same steps from tutorial. Works like a charm. Can you provide content of `democonsole.csproj`?

Comment: @KrivitskiyGrigoriy
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>